# Safe accessing inotified files

Tags: shell, inotifywait

In a shell script I want to wait for a certain file to appear

```
inotifywait -m -r -q -e close_write -e moved_to --format '%w/%f' $ARCHIVE_ROOT | while read FILE; do
# Call other programs which process the file like stat or sha1sum
done
```

I would have assumed the file to be valid while in the handling code. Sadly the file seems to disappear e.g. after being processed by `sha1sum`.
Did I miss something obvious, which is necessary to make the file last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many processes create temporary files and quickly delete them.  Such is the nature of progress.

To prevent a file from being deleted while your loop executes, use a *hard* link:

```
inotifywait -m -r -q -e close_write -e moved_to --format '%w/%f' $ARCHIVE_ROOT | while read FILE; do
    ln "$FILE" tmpfile$$ || continue
    sha1sum tmpfile$$
    rm tmpfile$$
done
```

If the file is destroyed before your while loop starts, there is nothing you can do.  If, however, it exists at the start of the loop, the use of a hardlink will ensure that it continues to exist as long as you need it.

The hard link with not stop other processes from changing the file.  If that is a problem, then a copy (`cp`) is necessary.

For this to work, the temporary file has to be on the same filesystem as the original.

If this application is security-sensitive, you may want to use `mktemp` or other such utility to generate the name for the temporary file.

Comment: So `inotifywait` would rather have to return both the path and inode of the file to work securely!?

Comment: Having the inode would still not solve the problem if the file has already been deleted before the inotifywait script has a chance to run.

Comment: Correct, but then I would assume for the inode to be reffed (by inotify) until all callbacks of inotify were called.